# User control variable not declared

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, user-controls

I have a variable that is declared in a user control.  It is the value of a drop down list in the user control.  When I try to use it in an If statement on an aspx page it says that the variable is not declared.  Is there a way to declare the variable on the aspx page or make it recognize that it is declared on the user control page?
Thank you

I'm calling the code at the top of the aspx page

```
<%@ Register src="pType.ascx" tagname="pType" tagprefix="uc2" %>
```

I'm using the if statement

```
<%If pt.SelectedValue = "1" Then%>
    \\do things 
    <%End If%>
```

In the control pt is defined by

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="pt" runat="server">
```

Comment: how are you embedding the user control in the aspx page. Maybe provide a code snippet of how you are embedding the control and trying to access the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I might need to see the code but have you tried

```
var v = pt.SelectedItem;

if (v == "1")
{
// do things
}
```

Note this code needs to be run in the code behind (the .cs) file, not the ascx or aspx file :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer but I really appreciate your time.  I added some code for clarification, does that make any sense to you?  Thank you!

Comment: This code should be used in the code behind for your control and not in the markup.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can access the properties of a user control in the aspx page.

What I know you can do is declare the User Control in code behind and dynamically add it to your page.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      //MyControl is the Custom User Control with a code behind file
      MyControl myControl = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx");

      if (myControl.SelectedValue == 1) {
         //do work
      }
      // User Control is a placeholder in your aspx page
      UserControlHolder.Controls.Add(myControl);

}
```